# How would I use a different row layout in custom CursorAdapter based on Cursor data?

Tags: android, listview, android-cursoradapter

**Background:** I'm trying to implement a messenging system in my app, and I'm writing a custom `CursorAdapter` to display the messages in a `ListView` in the chat window.  I want to use a different row layout for incoming and outgoing messages (information that is saved in the SQLite row in the cursor).  Each row has the same elements in it with the same IDs, but they are arranged differently.

**The Problem:** Currently, I have overridden `newView()` and `bindView()`.  When the `ListView` is first populated, it creates all of the `View`s perfectly, checking each row to see if it's either incoming or outgoing, and inflating the proper XML file.  However, when I scroll or a new message is added to the window, the adapter recycles `View`s for the wrong rows.  I would override `getView()`, but it is not passed the `Cursor` as a parameter, so I have no way of knowing whether the row should be incoming or outgoing.

I'm not looking for code, but rather, some suggestion for an elegant implementation.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: How long do you expect these lists to get?  If they are more than a few pages, not recycling views can cause scrolling/performance issues.

Comment: They need to support fairly long lists of messages, so I'd definitely like to recycle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are two possible solutions:

(1) Use a single layout for all items, which you can adjust when binding to show as desired.  The most straight-forward way would just to have the root view be a FrameLayout which contains N children for each of the different states, and you make one of them visible and all others gone when binding.  Of course you want to take care to not let this cause your items to explode in the number of views they contain.

(2) Implement Adapter.getItemViewType() http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemViewType(int) to tell the list view about the different types of items you have so it will recycle the correct one.

Comment: While the second answer is a bit of an extension of Bob's suggestion, I really like your first suggestion.  I think I'm going to go that route.  Thanks!

Comment: For posterity, I accomplished what I wanted by creating a very simple, two-level layout with 3 children in a `RelativeLayout`.  I then apply different `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` to the layout in `bindView()`.

Answer (score 0):

Just a few thoughts, I personnaly find the whole `ListView` and `CursorAdapter` combination to be a little... err... is bloated the right word? Would it just be simpler to have a `ScrollView`/ `LinearLayout` combination that will just add the appropriate `TextView` as requested?

But as for your solution, since the user seems to be unable to change the order of the messages as they are added, you could add a `ArrayList<String>` field to your custom `CursorAdapter` that will keep track of whether the messages are incoming or outgoing. Something like:

```
private ArrayList<String> cursorMonitor; //"incoming" and "outgoing" as your options.
```

...and then inside wherever the `ListView` gets populated just use

```
cursorMonitor.add(my_cursor.getString("outgoing_or_incoming"));
```

And then in the `getView()` you can override it and use the `cursorMonitor` to determine which layout you need to inflate.